# What is the best tools for NO SQL database with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, database, nosql

i am designing a small app with python3 and i need record some data in database.
I would like to use a non-relational database for ease.

I'm working on an ARM os (raspberry), i cannot use mongodb (their is no up to date release available)

what can I use instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cassandra and Docker.
Cassandra is a column database.